# NSURLConnection and Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to log in into a web page through an iPhone app. I'm using a NSURLConnection to try to connect. The app seems to be logging in correctly but I'm then getting redirected to a page that says I can't continue without Javascript enabled. I'm running all of this through the iPhone simulator that comes packaged with xcode. The curious part is that when I navigate to the same web page with the same information in safari in the iPhone simulator I don't get this reconnect, it sends me to the page I want.

Why is using the NSURLConnection giving me this redirect if I have Javascript enabled in the simulator and can navigate to it outside of the app? Thank you for any help.

Comment: So I've narrowed it down a bit. It doesnt matter that safari can access the page I want. The problem is that the app/NSURLConnection does not want to run the javascript redirect code on the web page. I still have no solutions though

Comment: As another update I'm now running two NSURLConnections back to back. The first is doing the login and getting taken to the "JAVAscript is disabled" page. The second one connects to the URL where the info I want is stored directly. So it appears as long as the session is open and I logged in correctly I can get my data.

I AM VERY UNHAPPY WITH THIS METHOD. I would much rather prefer a way of doing this process without having to resort to the method described above

Answer (score 2):

NSURLConnection does not interpret javascript. Safari does interpret javascript. If you need it to interpret javascript use UIWebView and actually display the webpage.

Your webpage should implement "graceful degradation". Which just means your site should work without any javascript. You can find plenty of documentation about graceful degradation if you google.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option because I am not the owner or operator of the website and have no way of getting those changes to be made. But you did let me know what I needed to know so thank you.